# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'radopen'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

To start, I am a telerik rookie and I have searched Telerik forums, I have posted on the forum (but no responses yet)  and S/O messages (including [Dynamically open a radwindow defined in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12770342/72324) ) but I still cannot resolve my issue.

I am attempting to open a radWindow from C# codebehind (using VS 2008, Telerik.Web.UI version 2012.2.724.35), however, I am getting this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or
>   method 'radopen'

My aspx code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenRadWindow() {
        var wnd = window.radopen("http://www.microsoft.com", null);
        wnd.setSize(300, 400);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "getting data", "OpenRadWindow();", true);
}
```

What could be causing the error?
**Update:** How can I get the library to load?

Comment: First thing to check would be that your page is really loading the library.

Comment: How would I determine that?

Comment: By looking at the source of the page in the browser.  There has to be a `<script>` tag that imports the library. (That is, if it's not obvious from your source code.)  Also check for errors in the browser console.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't see a "<script src="/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd......" on the page that is showing the error, but on other pages, where Telerik is used, I do see the <script> tag. I do have a "<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>" on the page that is showing the error. How can I get it to load the library?

Comment: I wish I could say, but I'm not an ASP.NET programmer :(  There must be some sort of header or something in other (working) pages that imports the script.

Comment: well, the header stuff is the "<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>". But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You mean here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesn-t-support-property-or-method-radopen.aspx? I see a response there that points to an answer to your question. And its exactly what I said here: [Dynamically open a radwindow defined in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770342/dynamically-open-a-radwindow-defined-in-javascript) 
.