# Object doesn't support property or method 'radopen' in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, client-side, radwindow

Before I asked, I took a look around first and found a couple solutions but those were based on calling the script server side and I am calling it from the client side.
I looked at this..
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770342/dynamically-open-a-radwindow-defined-in-javascript) and [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-doesn-t-support-property-or-method-radopen). So they were no help.

I keep getting an error stating

> Object doesn't support property or method 'radopen' in external javascript file

But I have it working in a different project in an external file. I have no idea why its acting like this.

My external code is

```
function GetModal(url, title, width, height) {
var oWindow = window.radopen(url, title, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why it was throwing that error. I forgot to add..

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server">
        <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server">

            </telerik:RadWindow>
        </Windows>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

to the markup.

No more error.